# Oscilloscope ground oscillating

Tags: ground, oscilloscope

I turn on the oscilloscope, work a little, then I remove the cables and after a while when I want to use it again, I notice the ground has moved 0.4 or 0.6 V upper or lower than it was half an hour ago. What could cause this problem?

Comment: the ground is changing very slowly while nothing is connected to ground or channel inputs.

Comment: Are you saying that when you connect it to your circuit it is 0.4-0.6V different or are you saying that if you leave it on for a while with nothing connected it drifts 0.4-0.6V?

Comment: when I leave it on for a while with nothing connected it drifts 0.4-0.6V

Comment: Ground = 0V unless you have a different 0V reference.

Comment: I think the mistake you're making is that having nothing connected isn't the same as ground, it's floating and will likely drift and be noisy, connect it to a known voltage source and leave it a while then see if it drifts.

Comment: that's how i noticed the problem, the voltage I was measuring was changing, so I left it open for a while and i noticed that it was changing itself even when i changed it to ground mode.

Comment: When you say "left it open" do you mean you removed the probe, or you removed the earth clip, or both? If you remove the earth clip, your display will obviously move around. Maybe post some photos so we can see what you´re seeing.

Comment: the problem may be in the safety ground of the oscilloscope. Check if the plug has three ports, one of them tied to earth. get the earth port contacted to one of your flower pots sand for a while, then remove the port fom the pot and put your multimetres negative tp into the pot, positive tp to the earth port. Observe the ac coupling if its changing. if it is other than 50 or 60 hz, then earth port is messed up.

Comment: Check your outlet for proper ground.  There are outlet testers available, inexpensively.   You could also try a new test lead.  Test leads are cheaply made.  Always have a spare.

Comment: Altho, test lead not a factor here.

Comment: seems like oscilloscope is the problem. thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An oscilloscope is a differential device. When a signal is applied between the ground and input of the scope the display is the difference of the two. Lets call the scope ground, REF to eliminate confusion with earth ground. The differential input is awesome because REF can be connected to many places other than 0V to inspect signals that wouldn't be seen otherwise.

The greatest problem is that in all scopes (except specialty ones) the REF is connected to earth ground (GND) through the power cord. This grounding necessitates that either the scope or the device under test (DUT) be floating. If neither the scope nor the DUT are floating, connecting REF to something hot will create a short and blow the ass out of your scope.

There are two test setups that are needed for proper testing. At least one needs to be met so your scope works well and does not explode. If both are met there is no problem.

1. The DUT is floating. This could mean that the DUT is battery powered. If the DUT plugs into mains power than the use of an isolation transformer is needed.
2. The scope is floating. This could mean that the scope is battery powered or plugged into an isolation transformer.

When connecting a floating device to a non floating device the floating device will reference itself to the non floating device. If the non floating device then has variation in its GND the floating device will simply move up and down, sort of riding the wave. You will never see the change in GND.

Even if the scope probe is shorted to REF directly all this would show is that there is no input offset. This is because, again, if there is a variation in GND the differential input will simply ride up and down with the variation always showing nothing.

From what you describe, i'm gathering you unhooked the probe and left the scope alone. This will show you garbage. With the input not connected to anything, it is floating. With a floating input the scope picks up crap from the environment. Attach a probe to the scope, short REF to the signal on the probe. If the signal stays at 0V then your scope is fine.